# find command for file size

Tags: linux, find

I need to get details on file size in the following find command.  I must be putting the `-size` option in the wrong place or else I should not be using that to get the file size's.

```
find CDR* -type f -newermt 10/15/2018 | head -n100 >filelist100.txt
```

Comment: there's no `-size` in the command you listed (yet)...

Comment: So you want to find files starting with CDR, or somewhere inside any directory starting with CDR, that were modified after yesterday. Of these files you want only the first 100. -- Or do you want the 100 largest of the files?

Comment: RTFM - Read the find(1) man page > `If the expression contains no actions other than -prune, -print is performed on all files for which the expression is true.` It's providing you only the file name, as implied/requested. If you want info on file size, you can either use the -size option with your expressions, or you can -exec something like `-ls -l` and output to a file, then sort those results

Comment: Your stated command demonstrates a severely flawed understanding of how `find` works. Please explain what exactly you're trying to accomplish, because what you're actually doing is so badly wrong it's impossible for us to tell what you expected to happen.

Answer (score 0):

```
find CDR* -type f -newermt 10/15/2018 -exec du -sh {} \; | 
head -n100 >filelist100.txt
```

Here is the find your find command with an execution of a `du -sh` command on the output.

You can of course change the `-exec` command to match the exact output that you need.